# jquery mobile ajax jump to another page but css not effect

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

here is a example page A jump page B ,page B  has itself css reference,when page A to B,the

css not effect, for example:

/* page A start */

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
       <a  href="B.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">this is A</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

/* page A end */

/* page B start */

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <style>
        a{
            color : red !important;
         }
        #a{
           height : 100px;
           width : 100px;
            color : red;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" >
      <a  href="A.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">this is B</a>
      <div id="a">bbb</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

/* page B end */

when A jump to B with ajax the color not change the 'div' not set height and width, so I

find put the '' tag in 'div' data-role="page" it effect,but is there any other

solution  to solve it? also use ajax and style put in B page

Answer (score 0):

Put style tag to body section.

```
<body>
<style>
    a{
        color : red !important;
     }
    #a{
       height : 100px;
       width : 100px;
        color : red;
     }
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: Have any other better solution ?

Comment: Check this link http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/#/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0):

When JQM loads the second page via ajax it ignores everything in the `<head>` section. This includes scripts and css. The best solution would be to create your own external css file that gets included into every page. Your probably thinking why would I do that if it ignores everything inside `<head>`. Well this is in case someone reloads the page or comes to that page via a link(email or social site). When you do this you will need to be more specific with your css. i.e.

```
#page2 a{
    color : red !important;
}
#page2 #a{
   height : 100px;
   width : 100px;
   color : red;
}
```